# Google Charts - HTML source being displayed in tooltips

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to display a Pie Chart using Google Charts, using HTML in the tooltips.
The problem I'm getting is that the HTML source is showing through. I've set html:true on the data column, I've set tooltip.isHtml in the options, and I'm really not sure what else to try now!
Here's my JS source:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart_1 );
function drawChart_1() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( [
['','',''],
['Thing 1' , 200 , '<b>Thing 1</b><br/>&pound;200 (14%)' ],
['Thing 2' , 400 , '<b>Thing 2</b><br/>&pound;400 (29%)' ],
['Thing 3' , 600 , '<b>Thing 3</b><br/>&pound;600 (43%)' ],
['Thing 4' , 200 , '<b>Thing 4</b><br/>&pound;200 (14%)' ],
]);
data.setColumnProperty(2,'role','tooltip');
data.setColumnProperty(2,'html','true');
data.setColumnProperty(2,'p',{'html':true});  // tried with, and without this (and the next) line
//data.setColumnProperty(2,'properties',{'html':true});

  var options = {"height":300,"pieSliceText":"none","tooltip.isHtml":true,"pieHole":0.5,"legend":"none","pieSliceTextStyle":"none","chartArea":{"width":"100%","height":"80%"},"slices":[{"color":"#959595"},{"color":"#616161"},{"color":"#005131"},{"color":"#e2e2e2"}]};
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById( 'piechart_div_1' ) );
  chart.draw( data , options );
}
```

So, does anyone know where I'm going wrong on this? Searching for this problem just points me in the direction of setting tooltip.isHtml to true, which I've already done. Some results pointed me in the direction of setting html:true on the data column - in the code, you can see a couple of attempts at that, which have had no affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple things...

first, you can provide the column definition in the array

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['' , '' , {type:"string" , role:"tooltip" , p:{"html":true}}],
  ...
]);
```

and definitely need `p:{"html":true}`

next, in the `options`, `tooltip` should be an object with keys

```
  "tooltip": {
    "isHtml":true
  },
```

vs.

`"tooltip.isHtml":true`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['','',{type:"string",role:"tooltip",p:{"html":true}}],
      ['Thing 1' , 200 , '<b>Thing 1</b><br/>&pound;200 (14%)' ],
      ['Thing 2' , 400 , '<b>Thing 2</b><br/>&pound;400 (29%)' ],
      ['Thing 3' , 600 , '<b>Thing 3</b><br/>&pound;600 (43%)' ],
      ['Thing 4' , 200 , '<b>Thing 4</b><br/>&pound;200 (14%)' ],
    ]);

    var options = {
      "height":300,
      "pieSliceText":"none",
      "tooltip": {
        "isHtml":true
      },
      "pieHole":0.5,
      "legend":"none",
      "pieSliceTextStyle":"none",
      "chartArea":{
        "width":"100%",
        "height":"80%"
      },
      "slices":[
        {"color":"#959595"},
        {"color":"#616161"},
        {"color":"#005131"},
        {"color":"#e2e2e2"}
      ]
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById( 'piechart_div_1' ) );
    chart.draw( data , options );
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart_div_1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that code worked fine and pointed me in the direction of my isHtml being wrongly constructed.  Did find that the p:{"html":true} was not actually needed in my code for some reason.